# mypy "Incompatible types" error when one @overload function calls another in __setitem__

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, mypy, python-3.10

I'm making a class that implements the `MutableSequence` contract and am having trouble type-hinting the getters & setters which take either a `slice` or a `SupportsIndex` instance as the index argument. In my application I have a `_normalise_index` function which turns negative relative indices and slices into positive ones by subtracting from `len` - e.g. `collection[:-1] -> collection[:5]`, but mypy is not happy about my overloads...

Here is a simplified example:

```
from typing import Iterable, SupportsIndex, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")


class Example:  # in my real code this is `class Example(typing.MutableSequence[T])`, but that's not required for this minrepro
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable[T]):
        self._lst = list(iterable)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._lst)

    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: slice) -> slice: ...
    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: SupportsIndex) -> int: ...

    def _normalise_index(self, index: slice | SupportsIndex) -> slice | int:
        "Convert -ve to +ve index - this makes sense for the real code..."
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return slice(
                0 if not index.start else self._normalise_index(index.start),
                len(self) if not index.stop else self._normalise_index(index.stop),
                index.step or 1,
            )
        else:
            return len(self) + idx if (idx := int(index)) < 0 else idx

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex, value: T) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: slice, value: Iterable[T]) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(  # line 34
        self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex | slice, value: T | Iterable[T]
    ) -> None:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        self._lst[normalised_index] = value  # line 38
```

... which gives 3 errors:

> ```
> main.py:34: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2
> main.py:38: error: Invalid index type "Union[int, slice]" for "List[T]"; expected type "SupportsIndex"
> main.py:38: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[T, Iterable[T]]", target has type "T")
> ```

[View in online mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=d012482555b9381e62757e7269dc5de9)

---

It looks like mypy is ignoring my overloads for `__setitem__` so it thinks `unsafe_index` could be a `slice` or a `SupportsIndex` and then it is only matching one of the overloads for `_normalise_index`. No idea why...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi are you sure? The errors don't mention `_normalised_index`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting your first error on python 3.8. For the latter, you're hitting python's overload limitation. You can `cast` your types to what the overloads state:

```
    def __setitem__(
        self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex | slice, value: T | Iterable[T]
    ) -> None:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        if isinstance(normalised_index, slice):
            self._lst[normalised_index] = cast(Iterable[T], value)
        else:
            self._lst[normalised_index] = cast(T, value)
```

Comment: is `cast` typesafe in the sense that value must be a Union or subtype of the type you are casting to (or Any), or does it basically just tell mypy `forget what you knew about this variable, it's actually this`. I'm wondering in case I were to refactor `__setitem__`  so that the cast is now no longer possible (e.g. if I change `T` to `U` or a concrete type, I would hope the cast would fail)

Comment: @Greedo no it's not at all type-safe. I don't believe there is a type-safe way of doing this. This is just minimal damage

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Do not repeat annotations in function signature if you use `@overload`:

```
from typing import Iterable, SupportsIndex, TypeVar, Union, overload

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[int, str])


class Example:      
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self._lst:list[T] = list(iterable)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._lst)

    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: slice) -> slice: ...  

    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: SupportsIndex) -> int: ...  

    def _normalise_index(self, index) -> slice | int:
        "Convert -ve to +ve index - this makes sense for the real code..."
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return slice(
                0 if not index.start else self._normalise_index(index.start),
                len(self) if not index.stop else self._normalise_index(index.stop),
                index.step or 1,
            )
        else:
            return len(self) + idx if (idx := int(index)) < 0 else idx

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex, value: T) -> None: ...  

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: slice, value: Iterable[T]) -> None: ... 

    def __setitem__(# line 34
        self, unsafe_index, value
    ) -> None:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        self._lst[normalised_index] = value  # line 38
    
class SI(SupportsIndex):

    def __index__(self, v):
        pass
    
x = Example([])._normalise_index(slice(1, 2))
y = Example([])._normalise_index(SI())
Example([])[3] = 4
Example([])[3:4] = [4]
```